# why samba share speed is so slow?

Tags: networking, samba, file-sharing

I have a PC connected to a modem with Lan and my laptop is connected with wifi. Both of them use ubuntu. The Lan link speed is 100 Mb/s and wifi speed is 72 Mb/s.I want to copy some files from my PC to laptop. I shared my files with samba so that I can access them in laptop. When I copy files into the laptop, copying speed never gets more than 5 Mb/s. So it takes too much to copy all the files. How can I increase this speed?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're not mistaken on speed units?

Keep in mind that speeds shown for WiFi and LAN networks are most of the time represented in Megabits.

But browser and file manager tend to show speed values in Megabytes.

For example for standard WiFi on 2,4 GHz modem the top speed is 72 Mbps, which is around 9 MB/s. But in real world there are many obsticles for WiFi signals, that slows down the speed over it to much less speeds, like 40-50 Mbps, which gives you  only 5 to 6 MB/s.

The reason why WiFi works unstable and slower than LAN is because of the signals from different WiFi networks interfering with each other. On this frequency there is a narrow range of channels on which WiFi can work.

So the solution for your will be to either connect your laptop over wired LAN, or upgrade your WiFi modem to a 5 GHz device, which has much better performance.

Comment: I'm not sure about speed unit, but on setting it shows " Link speed: 72 Mb/s"

Comment: That's right, and it's the top speed of WiFi over 2,4 GHz transmission, but only in the ideal world. Most of the time it's slower than that and you'll get only 40 or 50 Mb/s. You can test it using i.e. https://www.speedtest.net/. But as I said, browser or file manager often shows speed in MB/s, not in Mb/s so you need to divide this value by 8. For example: 8 Mb/s = 1 MB/s, 40 Mb/s = 5 MB/s and so on.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the difference between MB/s and Mb/s @Comar